# How to stream titan graph using gephi?

Tags: titan, gephi, graphstream

I want to stream titan graph by using gephi. I follow the instruction from here 
http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0.M7/#gephi-plugin

I'm using Gephi 0.9.1, open new project and start master server in gephi.
Then i start gremlin console with gephi plugin activated and connect to gephi, but got error 'Not Found' as below:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.gephi
==>Connection to Gephi - http://localhost:8080/workspace0 with stepDelay:1000, startRGBColor:[0.0, 1.0, 0.5], colorToFade:g, colorFadeRate:0.7
gremlin> :> g
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
Not Found
Display stack trace? [yN] y
groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Not Found
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:642)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1074)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$1.handleResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:222)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:506)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.post(HTTPBuilder.java:343)
..........
```

I don't know why this error occurred. Please show me how to stream titan graph using Gephi. Thank for you help.

Answer (score 2):

That's a really old version of the TinkerPop docs. I'm not sure the instructions changed that much between M7 and GA, but you should definitely look at the docs current to the version attached to Titan. In other words you want version [TinkerPop 3.0.1-incubating](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/pom.xml#L62). You can find that documentation here:

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gephi-plugin

I would say that the directions for making this happen are fairly "step-by-step", so perhaps you missed something important. My best guess from your error is that you did not enable the streaming plugin in Gephi before you tried to send the graph. My second best guess is that you are trying to use the newer version of Gephi 0.9 which is does not yet have the streaming plugin brought up to date with that version.  There could be some [incompatibility](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/hc6XJR6to80/_y3gM4RkAgAJ) there.  If this is the case, I would revert back to 0.8.x beta as all the docs are based on that version of Gephi.

EDIT: Note that as of TinkerPop 3.2.1, Gephi 0.9.x is supported.

Comment: Thank you, it seems GraphStreaming plugin version 1.0.0 not work with Gephi 0.9.1.  Gephi 0.8.2 not work with java 7.8, so i need to wait for next update of GraphStreaming.

Comment: hmm - i thought i'd been using Gephi 0.8 with Java 8. are you sure that is the case?

Comment: i download gephi 0.8.2 version for mac os here https://github.com/gephi/gephi/releases/tag/v0.8.2 . Gephi cannot open on macos.

Comment: ah - mac - well, it works on ubuntu and windows afaik

Comment: Hi, it seems that you must submit the entire graph to gephi stream, then you can submit the traversal to gephi, is that true? But normally the graph very big in titan, so it's not possible to submit the entire graph, so what can i do?

Comment: Gephi isn't built to visualize massive graphs and trying to visualize graphs with millions of edges really isn't all that useful anyway. You should subgraph Titan to the parts you are interested in and then submit that subgraph to gephi. http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step

Comment: just an FYI.. probably old news. Looking about i see Stephen made a commit circa Mar 16 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/bwHs7ldex-Y. If i use 3.2.1 snapshot is it expected to work on mac now?

Comment: i believe it was tested on mac by someone and i was told it worked, but i don't remember for sure.